# mefx does not list an importer

Tags: c#, mef

I have a MEF-based modular app that has started to fail to import classes.  In the course of debugging, I've been using the `mefx` tools to try to track down the core issue. In short, all of my `[Export]` declarations appear to be correct, but none of the `Import` or `ImportMany` attributes seem to be processed correctly.

Hopefully this is a simple mistake on my part, but the application was working until recently.

Here is a very short test application I've written along with the corresponding `mefx` output.

```
using System.ComponentModel.Composition;

namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    public class Class1
    {
        [Import]
        public Class2 myclass;
    }

    [Export]
    public class Class2
    {
    }
}
```

And the `mexf` output

```
> mefx /file:ClassLibrary1.dll /parts
ClassLibrary1.Class2

> mefx /file:ClassLibrary1.dll /exports
ClassLibrary1.Class2

> mefx /file:ClassLibrary1.dll /imports
[blank]
```

I would have expected `Class1` to be listed as an importer.  Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot import in a class not referenced by MEF.

Try:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
{
    [Export]
    public class Class1
    {
        [Import]
        public Class2 myclass;
    }

    [Export]
    public class Class2
    {
    }
}
```

You could also import it in the constructor:

```
namespace ClassLibrary1
    {
        [Export]
        public class Class1
        {
            [ImportingConstructor]
            public Class1(Class2 c2)
            {
                myclass = c2;
            }

            public Class2 myclass;
        }

        [Export]
        public class Class2
        {
        }
    }
```

Also, use the ServiceLocator to get Class1 (don't use the "new" keyword).

```
Class1 myClass1 = ServiceLocator.Current.GetExport<Class1>();
```

Comment: This was not the cause of my problem, but I learned something new!